# Requesting php from JavaScript results in an 502 Gateway error

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to request a php file from Javascript. I get a error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)`

Here are my files:
**web/index.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
<script>
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let response = null;
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.readyState);
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            response = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    http.open("GET", "resources/php/test.php", false);
    http.send();
    console.log(response);
</script>
</html>
```

**web/resources/php/test.php**

```
<?php
echo 'test';
```

And this is my output:

```
1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
4
null
```

I also tried the asynchronous approach. But when doing so the `readyState` will stuck at 1.

A much more simple approach looks like this:

```
<script>
    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", "resources/php/test.php", false);
    http.send();
    console.log(http.response);
</script>
```

It also won't work and results in the following output:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)
!doctype html><title>502 Bad Gateway</title><h1 style="text-align: center">502 Bad Gateway</h1>
```

Im trying to read a php-file from a JavaScript file.

Comment: I tried it with PHPstorm. Once i tried it via a local server it worked. Do you know any fix for PHPstorm specifically?

Comment: What happens if you open test.php directly?